# Find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $A$ being the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 1 \\
    4       &0 &4 \\
    -1       & 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}

I found the characteristic polynomial to be $$ 4\lambda-\lambda^3$$

With Eigenvalues of
$\lambda_1 = -2$
$\lambda_2 = 2$
$\lambda_3 = 0$

I'm not sure how to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP$ is diagonal. A friend and I keep getting different answers. My notes aren't really making a lot of sense about how to do it, and [my professor is on strike.](http://pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/2016/10/19/faculty-officially-on-strike-at-state-universities/) My notes say to take the matrix $A-\lambda_iI$ and plug in the Eigenvalues for $\lambda$, RREF it, then find the $x,y,z$ but that's where I keep getting different answers.

Any help?

Comment: Find the eigenvectors; in the basis of eigenvectors the matrix will be diagonal. More concretely, eigenvectors will be columns of $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry, the matrix was typed wrong, its not a -1 in that first row third value its just a 1.

Comment: Notice that $P$ is not unique (for instance, if you multiply P by a diagonal matrix, that matrix also do the work), so If you and your friend are getting different results doesn't mean that one of you is wrong. To verify your answers just compute explicitly $P^{-1} A P$ with the $P$ each of you found, if you obtain a diagonal matrix, then it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A-2I$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
4 & -2 & 4 \\
-1 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{\text{elimination}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so an eigenvector is
$$
v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
but there's no uniqueness and every nonzero scalar multiple would be as good.

Find $v_2$ relative to $0$ and $v_3$ relative to $-2$. Then the matrix $P$ will be $P=[v_1\;v_2\;v_3]$ and the diagonal will be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Permuting the eigenvectors in $P$ will accordingly permute the eigenvalues along the diagonal. There's no unique answer.